# how to solve null pointer exception for Hibernate query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I keep getting a null pointer exception for the HQl query that I have created, I am building a webapp using spring + hibernate:

here are the code snippets:

DAO which is showing problem -

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<Products> getCartForUser(){
    List<Products> l=null;
    try
    {
        sess.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "SELECT Products.productName, Products.unitPrice, Products.Category" + 
                " FROM Products,Cart,Userinfo" + 
                " where (Userinfo.userName=Cart.userName  AND Userinfo.userName = 'user1')" + 
                " AND Products.productId=Cart.productId";
        l = sess.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return l;
}
```

entity classes:

cart-

```
package model.entity;

 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
 import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Cart {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private int cartId;



public int getCartId() {
    return cartId;
}

public void setCartId(int cartId) {
    this.cartId = cartId;
}





public Userinfo getUserInfo() {
    return userInfo;
}

public void setUserInfo(Userinfo userInfo) {
    this.userInfo = userInfo;
}

public Products getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Products product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Cart() {}
public Cart( Userinfo userInfo, Products product) {
    super();


    this.userInfo = userInfo;
    this.product = product;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME")
private Userinfo userInfo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCTID")
private Products product;


 }
```

product-

```
 package model.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Products {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productId;
    @Size(min=1)
    private String productName;
    @Min(value=1, message = "Value cannot be zero or negative")
    private double unitPrice;
    @Size(min=1)
    private String productDescription;
    @Size(min=1)
    private String category; 
    @Min(value = 1, message = " Quantity should be greater than zero and positive")
    @Max(value= 99, message = " Quantity limit exceeded, value should be less than 100")
    private int productQty;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userInfo")
    private List<Cart> cart = new ArrayList<>();

    public Products() {}

    public Products(int productId, String productName, double unitPrice, String productDescription, String category, int productQty, List<Cart> cart) {
        super();
        this.productQty = productQty;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.category = category;
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public List<Cart> getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(List<Cart> cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public int getProductQty() {
        return productQty;
    }

    public void setProductQty(int productQty) {
        this.productQty = productQty;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }




}
```

userinfo entity -

```
package model.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Userinfo {

    @Id
    private String userName;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;
    private String emailId;
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private boolean enabled;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Authorities> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userInfo")
    private List<Cart> cart = new ArrayList<>();


    public Userinfo(){}

    public Userinfo(String userName, String emailId, String password, boolean enabled, List<Authorities> authorities, List<Cart> cart) {
        super();
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.userName= userName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.password= password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public List<Cart> getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(List<Cart> cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public List<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Authorities> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

So what I want to do is display the products for a specific user which are present in his cart.

the error that I am getting is:

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when I tried running other simple queries the code works fine but when I use multiple tables I get the above error. I have not included the spring files but if you need them I'll add them.

stack trace

```
 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ProjectFE/showcart: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.daoimpl.CartDAOImpl.getCartForUser(CartDAOImpl.java:58)
    at controller.CartController.showCart(CartController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    ... 79 more
```

Comment: why do you have \n and \r in your query? do you understand why that doesn't make any sense? on what line do you get that Exception thrown?

Comment: yeah even after removing that it does not work

Comment: still you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: what would be that ? I don't undesrtand. can you be more specific ?

Comment: Where is `sess` coming from?

Comment: from the constructor ` public CartDAOImpl() {
  sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

} `

Comment: can u share full stacktrace

Comment: yes did that check above, please.

Comment: Don't do that in the constructor. Also you shouldn't be using `HibernateUtil`. Instead inject the `SessionFactory` and use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession` to obtain the current thread bound session based on the transaction.

Comment: Ok so I did as you said but the problem persist, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Also I have updated the stack trace.

Comment: Where is line 58 of CartDAOImpl.java?

Comment: line 58 is Session sess = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();